# Replace Nouns with "Marklar"

Tags: java, replace, matcher

im trying to read the String, then replace all Words with Uppercase Letters
with "Marklar"
It should just look like this :

```
> Hello 
< Marklar

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

String input = scanner.nextLine();
input=input.replaceAll("\\b[A-Z]\\b", "Marklar");

System.out.println(input);
```

This doesn't work... Anyone with an idea ?

Comment: I have an idea: your regular expression does not match words except for single letter uppercase ones.

Answer (score 2):

You will currently only replace single, isolated uppercase letters. Add a quantifier to match one or more:

```
"\\b[A-Z]+\\b"
         ^ "one or more"
```

and expand the character class if you want to match lowercase letters too:

```
"\\b[A-Za-z]+\\b"
```

Comment: Im trying to replace the whole Noun like "Hello" with "Marklar" , it seems like i cant acces the word itself . If the regex is just  `[A-Z]` , i get "Marklarello" instead of just Marklar , which is what i want.

Comment: The `[A-Z]` character class only matches uppercase letters. If you want to match lowercase letters too.... try `[A-Za-z]`.

Comment: or. `"\\b[A-Z][a-z]*\\b"` meaning exactly 1 uppercase letter followed by any amount of lowercase letters or "Any Uppercase Word"

Comment: Thats exactly what i was searching for . Thank you very much :)